# When does $\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_0^1\frac1{x^\alpha}\sin\frac1x\sin nxdx$ exist?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, definite-integrals

> **Question**
>   Given $\alpha<3$, when does $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_0^1\frac1{x^\alpha}\sin\frac1x\sin nxdx$$ exist?

Numerical evidence suggests this limit exists iff $\alpha<3/2$.
**Motivation** I'm trying to find another counterexample for the statement "Riemann-Lebesgue lemma is still true if we turn the condition of Lebesgue-integrable to simply 'the improper integral converges'".
It is already proven by Tang, that this limit does exist when $\alpha=1$.
**Adapted Proof**
$$\int_0^{n^{-3/2}}\frac1{x^{3/2-\varepsilon}}\sin\frac1x\sin nxdx\to0$$
Substituting $y=\sqrt nx$, $$\int_{n^{-3/2}}^1\ \frac1{x^{3/2-\varepsilon}}\sin\frac1x\sin nxdx=\int_{1/n}^{\sqrt n}\frac{n^{1/4-\varepsilon/2}}{y^{3/2-\varepsilon}}\sin\frac{\sqrt n}y\sin (y\sqrt n)dy\\
=\int_{1/n}^{\sqrt n}\frac{n^{1/4-\varepsilon/2}}{y^{3/2-\varepsilon}}\left(\sum \frac\pm2\cos\left[\sqrt n\left(\frac1y\pm y\right)\right]\right)dy$$
Substituting $z=\frac1y\pm y=:\phi(resp.\ \psi)(y)$,
$$|I|\le n^{1/4-\varepsilon/2}\left[\int_2^{\phi(\sqrt n)}+\int_2^{\phi(1/n)}\right]\cos(z\sqrt n)\left|\frac1{(z^2-4)^{3/4-\varepsilon/2}}-\frac1{(z^2+4)^{3/4-\varepsilon/2}}\right|dz\\
+n^{1/4-\varepsilon/2}\int_{-2}^2\cos(z\sqrt n)\frac1{(z^2+4)^{3/4-\varepsilon/2}}dz\\
+n^{1/4-\varepsilon/2}\left(\int_{\phi(1/n)}^{\psi(1/n)}+\int_{\phi(\sqrt n)}^{\psi(\sqrt n)}\right)\cos(z\sqrt n)\frac1{(z^2+4)^{3/4-\varepsilon/2}}dz\\
=:A+B+C$$
I can only prove $B\to 0$, I failed to prove $A,C\to0$. Any idea how to prove my conjecture that $L\to0$ iff $\alpha<3/2$?

Comment: This is a quick guess: for $A$, we have $\phi(\sqrt{n})$, $\phi(1/n) \rightarrow \infty$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$. If you replace $m = \sqrt{n}$ then your integrals look like $\int_2^\infty \cos(mz)f(z)dz$ which is the real part of $\int_2^\infty e^{imz}f(z)dz = \int_2^\infty e^{img(z)}f(z)dz$ where $g(z) = z$ is the phase and $f(z)$ is the amplitude. By stationary phase, $g$ is never critical on $(2, \infty)$ so this oscillatory integral is $o(m^{-1/2}) = o(n^{-1/4})$ which leaves $A = o(n^{-\epsilon/2})$.